# allowing django-oauth-toolkit to issue jwt instead of random strings

Tags: python, django

I understand that **django-oauth-toolkit** is using *oauthlib* and *oauthlib* provides an example on the implementation of using *jwt* instead of *random strings*.

However, I don't understand how I can get **django-oauth-toolkit** to issue *jwt* instead of *random strings*. Can anyone give an example implementation or git repo on how we can do this?

```
path('o/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
```

I am not sure how we can change the views in that import lines to customise it to allow *jwts*

Comment: I don't think it's been implemented yet on django-oauth-toolkit, follow the issue here https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit/issues/397. Maybe you can create a PR once figured out

Answer (score 1):

You can use `django-oauth-toolkit-jwt`. It is available in the repository https://github.com/Humanitec/django-oauth-toolkit-jwt.

Installation
Add to your pip requirements:

```
git+https://github.com/Humanitec/django-oauth-toolkit-jwt#egg=django-oauth-toolkit-jwt
```

Generate keys
In order to generate a RS256 (RSA Signature with SHA-256) public and private keys, execute the following:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f jwtRS256.key # don't add passphrase
$ openssl rsa -in jwtRS256.key -pubout -outform PEM -out jwtRS256.key.pub
$ cat jwtRS256.key
$ cat jwtRS256.key.pub
```

Producer configuration
To use this library to issue a token, configure the project as it follows:

Add oauth2_provider and oauth2_provider_jwt to your INSTALLED_APPS:

## settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'oauth2_provider',
    'oauth2_provider_jwt',
)
```

Include the new oauth URLs:

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^oauth/', include('oauth2_provider_jwt.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider_jwt')),
]
```

Add to your MIDDLEWARE the following:

## settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware',
]
```

And finally add a custom backend authentication:

## settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    ...
    'oauth2_provider.backends.OAuth2Backend',
)
```

Now we need to set up a JWT_ISSUER variable in our config, which will be the name of the issuer. Take the RSA256 private key that we genreated before and store it in a JWT_PRIVATE_KEY_RSA_ variable *. For example:

## settings.py

```
JWT_ISSUER = 'OneIssuer'
JWT_PRIVATE_KEY_RSA_ONEISSUER = """
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBOAIBAAJAbCmbRUsLrsv0/Cq7DVDpUooPS1V2sr0EhTZAZmJhid2o/+ya/28m
...
6D0+csaGDlZ9GbrTpTJUObNENNHqfrHGfqzDxQ==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
"""
```